How should I correctly format an IP address so the Meta Conversions API doesn't error
I'm able to send a conversion to the Meta Conversions API using PHP and CURL.  It is working so I am not trying to troubleshoot either PHP or CURL.  We can assume they work, data is being collected.
To increase my trust score it is better to send more data.  That way Meta can more easily match it up with the actual user and also help Meta to send other similar users so I can get more conversions.
When I try to send the IP address I get a message saying the IP address is invalid. It looks like a normal IP address to me when I var_dump it in PHP. i.e. something like this 62.31.39.161.  Var_dump shows it to be a string.
message":"Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2804007,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Invalid IP address","error_user_msg":"The IP address you've entered is invalid. Enter a valid IP address.","fbtrace_id":"AEoKrOjkl4D7f-c4GCcxywC"}}"
The Meta payload helper says I do NOT need to hash the IP address. Accordingly, I haven't.
I saw another question used an incomplete IP address.  That is definitely not the thing to do, although I tested it all the same.
Here's why you shouldn't do that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/customer-information-parameters/.
Previously there was an error message saying it needed to be a string, but my var_dump now shows I have correctly created a string using PHP.  And it no longer returns the error, so I can assume I have overcome the string issue.
What else could I need to do to get Meta to accept the IP address I am sending?
Here is the PHP I am using to call the IP address. A var_dump shows it as a string with no spaces at either end 62.31.39.161.
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

show the actual code that builds up the reqeuest payload, probably u have an error there ...

https://github.com/facebookincubator/Facebook-Pixel-for-Wordpress/blob/c51b7ac7e241a01ac740fbfc91f03d312c1438e1/core/ServerEventFactory.php#L64
This is facebook's official way of fetching ip address.
test cases seem to indicate what you have is right.
https://github.com/facebookincubator/Facebook-Pixel-for-Wordpress/blob/c51b7ac7e241a01ac740fbfc91f03d312c1438e1/__tests__/core/ServerEventFactoryTest.php#L83
just confirm that the ip address is not in private space (like 10.x.x.x) or (192.168.x.x)

No it's a legitimate external email address.

Also welcome to the community @Vivek K.  Thanks for your answer.

I note they are using the pixel and I'm using the API, could that be the difference?
